# Are questions about felling trees on topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

I could see arguments about this being both on and off topic. I (once) have taken down a tree, milled it with hand tools. We have had some question about [green-wood](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/green-wood) but none that are devoted to the actually felling of trees.

How do we feel about these types of questions? I have a couple *basic* examples...

- Safety precautions when felling trees
- How to ensure direction of tree when falling
- How can I tell if the wood is too "dead" to be milled.
- Tips for identifying trees that are *not* ideal for lumber.

Some of these could be seen as forestry questions. That is why I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm more than willing to give some answers to these questions, however, I'm not sure the first two really qualify as 'woodworking', at least as asked.

> Safety precautions when felling trees
>
> How to ensure direction of tree when falling

These two certainly feel much more acceptable as woodworking questions.

> How can I tell if the wood is too "dead" to be milled.
>
> Tips for identifying trees that are not ideal for lumber.

Since I both fell trees and mill them into lumber I can have some answers for all of them, but depending on how the question is phrased not sure all are appropriate for WW.